# How can I create an extension for Visual Studio that can interface with TFS directly?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, version-control, visual-studio-extensions

I am attempting to create an extension that will periodically check to see if the user has the latest version of all files in a specific project or branch. This specific project/branch is going to be determined by what item is checked out for editing. The reason for creating this extension is to create reminders every time a file becomes unsynced. This will prevent merging into items that are out of date.

I am also working with Gated Check-ins, so it would be advantageous if I could check for latest version after a gated build succeeds.

I am having trouble finding the APIs for TFS integration when making an extension for visual studio. I am also having trouble finding an API to use to make a direct TFS extension. I am assuming this is because everything that has to do with TFS commands should be done using TFS command line commands.

I am running TFS and VS 2015.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NuGet packages of TFS API:

[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client/)

[Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/)

[Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/)

All the DLL's also stored in the following location, you can take them and use in your project:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer
```

A good tutorial on how to use the API you can find [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2011/05/18/tfs-api-index-parts-1-to-37/).